# How many ways to get from a corner to an opposite corner.

Tags: combinatorics

For example if we have a $1$ by $2$:

[image]

There are $4$ ways to get to A to F without being in the same place more than once.

This can be solved by a tree diagram.

[image]

What about a general $n$ by $k$? Tree diagrams get messy for $2$ by $2$s...

Comment: Seems like this is what you're interested in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_path

Comment: But S W complicates it.. @Math1000

Comment: I vaguely remember a talk by Donald Knuth in which he said that this problem seemed unapproachable, until the discovery of binary decision diagrams.  I don't remember the details, but I see that volume 4 of Knuth's _The Art of Computer Programming_ has a discussion of BDDs, which may treat this problem, and you can also listen to [a talk by Knuth about BDDs](http://myvideos.stanford.edu/player/slplayer.aspx?coll=ea60314a-53b3-4be2-8552-dcf190ca0c0b&co=18bcd3a8-965a-4a63-a516-a1ad74af1119&o=true) which may discuss this problem.